# Different behavior between mongo and mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In the mongo shell I can do this:

```
db.getCollection('usercourses').update({
  _id:ObjectId("54bee7c6ababf28b4ea5a07f")},
  {
    $unset:{
      'steps.0.topic':''
    }
  },
{strict:false})
```

And it'll delete the "topic" field from the object inside the array, from the document found.

But when I do this in mongoose:

```
function() {
    return UserCourses.findQ()
    .then(function(uCourse){
        return Q.all(uCourse.map(worker))
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}

function worker(uCourse) {
    return Q.all(uCourse.steps.map(
    function(step,i){       
        var field1 = 'steps.'+i+'.topic';

        return UserCourses.updateQ({_id:uCourse._id},
        {
            $unset:{field1:''},
        },
        {strict:false});
    }
))
}
```

Nothing happens.

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're trying to unset a field called `field1` (because ES5 doesn't have [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names)):

```
$unset : { field1 : '' }
```

Instead, you need to do this:

```
var obj = {};
obj['steps.'+i+'.topic'] = '';
...
$unset : obj
```